# How to use different serdes for different processors in Kafka Streams?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a topology where I have 2 different source topics (2 sub-topologies).
One of them is in Avro format and the other is JSON.
Is there a way to use different Serdes for different processors?
I have seen that for store there is `Consumed.with()` but I don't see any thing as such for processors.

Apart from writing my own serializer or de-serializer which differentiates between the topics and serializes/deserializes accordingly, is there a configuration to use different serdes?

Comment: There's also a Produced class. Not sure if that answers the question. You can also create a serde from any serializer combo

Comment: @cricket_007 In topology? Can I specify it for each processor individually?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with KStream api, but if the dsl has it, then processors should too

Comment: For example, the main reason you're able to set Consumed is because a previous node would have had to be setup with Produced (unless using the default defined in the stream config)

Comment: I am using processor API, in streams there is `stream(topic, Consumed.with())`

Comment: There is also `to(topic, Produced.with())` and `through(topic, Produced.with())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Topology class contains the `addSource` method with `Serializer` and `Deserializer`

```
Topology addSource(String sourceName, Deserializer keyDeserializer, Deserializer valueDeserializer, String... topics)
```